# Basic Packet sniffer written in python for kali linux is running slowly

Tags: python-3.x, packet-sniffers

The program is supposed to print out raw bits in binary form and its not doing that :

```
import socket

def main():
    conn=socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.ntohs(3))
    data=conn.recvform(65500)
    print(data)
main()
```

I don't generate any errors, but when I run the python sniffer app, it runs for several minutes and never prints out any binary bits of raw data as I would expect it to.

Comment: The first thing I would do to start debugging this issue is to vastly reduce the amount of data being read - 65500 is a pretty large amount. Why not start with a smaller size (2048, maybe) until you get things working, and then **slowly** increase the size?

Comment: I tried doing that and I am still getting the same issue

Comment: fixed the issue. It turns out that I needed to actually go to a website in order for the app to work

Comment: Why would you think you could sniff packets without having an actual connection established with traffic between you?